# Flutter Change Dropdown arrow color

Tags: flutter, dart, colors, dropdown

How to change Dropdown arrow color?

**Here is what I want**:

[image]

**This is what I get**

[image]

**My widget:**

```
            DropdownButtonHideUnderline (
          child: DropdownButton<String>(
            isExpanded: true,
            value: dropdownValue,
            onChanged: (String newValue) {
              setState(() {
                dropdownValue = newValue;
              });
            },
            items: <String>['Bank Deposit', 'Mobile Payment', 'Cash Pickup']
                .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value),
              );
            })
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
```

I tried wrapping with Theme and changing Brightness, but it changes arrow from White to Black only. I want to use some other color.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This can be done with `icon:` property in `DropdownButton`

```
DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
            child: DropdownButton<String>(
              isExpanded: true,
              value: dropdownValue,
              onChanged: (String newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  dropdownValue = newValue;
                });
              },
              hint: Text('Select'),
              icon: Icon(                // Add this
                Icons.arrow_drop_down,  // Add this
                color: Colors.blue,   // Add this
              ),
              items: <String>['Bank Deposit', 'Mobile Payment', 'Cash Pickup']
                  .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: Text(value),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @anmol.majhail, anyway found something simpler using **iconEnabledColor** property.

```
               DropdownButtonHideUnderline (
          child: DropdownButton<String>(

            iconEnabledColor: Colors.indigo, // game changer

            isExpanded: true,
            value: dropdownValue,
            onChanged: (String newValue) {
              setState(() {
                dropdownValue = newValue;
              });
            },
            items: <String>['Bank Deposit', 'Mobile Payment', 'Cash Pickup']
                .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value),
              );
            })
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Favas, yes it is really a game changer :)